# Работа с двумерным массивом в Си

Tags: c, массивы, функции

Дан массив, нужно в отдельной функции найти число из этого массива, наиболее близкое к среднему значению в массиве.

```
double FindNearElement(int numStr, int numCol, int a[][numCol])
{
    double aver = 0.0, minDif, dif;
    int i, j, sum = 0, numPos = 0;
    int elStr, elCol;
    printf("%d %d\n",numStr,numCol);
    for (i = 0; i < numStr; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < numCol; ++j)
            printf("%3d  ", a[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    for (i = 0; i < numStr; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < numCol; j++)
            if (a[i][j] > 0)
            {
                printf("%d\n", a[i][j]);
                sum += a[i][j];
                ++numPos;
            }
    printf("%d %d\n",sum,numPos);       
    if (numPos > 0)
    {
        aver = (double)sum/(numPos);
        printf("%f\n",aver);
        }
    else
        return aver;


    elStr = elCol = 0;
    minDif = aver - a[0][0];
    printf("%d", minDif);
    for (i = 0; i < numStr; ++i)
        for (j = 0; j < numCol; ++j)
        {
            dif = fabs(aver - a[i][j]);
            if (dif < minDif)
            {
                minDif = dif;
                elStr = i;
                elCol = j;
            }
        }
    return aver;
}
```

1)Массив передается криво. Например, если передать массив 3*3, заполненный "12",то вторая строчка приходит обнуленной/полной какой-то белиберды
2)Непонятно что происходит на этапе подсчета `minDif`, как я понимаю, она почему -то берет не значение, а адрес
Почему так происходит и как надо переделать, чтобы корректно обрабатывался массив?
Для полноты картины лаю полный листинг

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define N 5 
#define M 6 

double FindNearElement(int numStr, int numCol, int a[][numCol]);

int main(void)
{
    double aver;
    int a[N][M], numStr, numCol, i, j, elStr, elCol;

    do 
    {
        printf("Enter number of strings: ");
        scanf("%d", &numStr);

        if (numStr < 1 || numStr > N)
            printf("Number of strings must be > 1 and <= %d\n", N);
    } 
    while (numStr < 1 || numStr > N);

    do 
    {
        printf("Enter number of columns: ");
        scanf("%d", &numCol);

        if (numCol < 1 || numCol > M)
            printf("Number of columns must be > 1 and <= %d\n", M);
    } 
    while (numCol < 1 || numCol > M);

    printf("Enter matrix:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < numStr; ++i)
        for (j = 0; j < numCol; ++j)
        {
            printf("Enter element A[%d][%d]: ", i, j);
            scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
        }

    printf("\nEntered matrix:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < numStr; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < numCol; ++j)
            printf("%3d  ", a[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    aver = FindNearElement(numStr, numCol, a);

    if (i != -1 && j != -1)
        printf("\nElement nearest to average %.2lf of positive elements: %d\n", aver, a[i][j]);
    else
        printf("\nMatrix have not positive elements!\n");

    getch();
    return 0;
}


double FindNearElement(int numStr, int numCol, int a[][numCol])
{
    double aver = 0.0, minDif, dif;
    int i, j, sum = 0, numPos = 0;
    int elStr, elCol;
    printf("%d %d\n",numStr,numCol);
    for (i = 0; i < numStr; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < numCol; ++j)
            printf("%3d  ", a[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    for (i = 0; i < numStr; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < numCol; j++)
            if (a[i][j] > 0)
            {
                printf("%d\n", a[i][j]);
                sum += a[i][j];
                ++numPos;
            }
    printf("%d %d\n",sum,numPos);       
    if (numPos > 0)
    {
        aver = (double)sum/(numPos);
        printf("%f\n",aver);
        }
    else
        return aver;


    elStr = elCol = 0;
    minDif = aver - a[0][0];
    printf("%d", minDif);
    for (i = 0; i < numStr; ++i)
        for (j = 0; j < numCol; ++j)
        {
            dif = fabs(aver - a[i][j]);
            if (dif < minDif)
            {
                minDif = dif;
                elStr = i;
                elCol = j;
            }
        }
    return aver;
}
```

Comment: 1) Приведите пример массива, который вы передаёте в функцию. Не очень понятно, что означает _если передать массив 3*3, заполненный "12"_. 2) `minDif = aver - a[0][0];` пропустили функцию `fabs`. 3) `printf("%d", minDif);` — некорректный спецификатор типа, нужен `f`.

Comment: удали вообще циклы с printf. обьяви aver  как uint .может ты  неправильно инициализируешь массив

Comment: может проще вообще весь код программы вставить?

Comment: @wololo чуть позже подредактирую вопрос

Comment: Раз вы считаете сумму и далее `aver` только для элементов больших нуля, то и `dif` надо вычислять только для них. Добавьте `if (a[i][j] > 0) { ...` перед вычислением `dif` (и напечатайте, все  же, искомые `elStr` и `elCol`)

Comment: Кстати, нет необходимости работать с массивом как с двумерным. Можно сделать так: `for (int i = 0; i < numStr * numCol; ++i)`. Поможет избавиться от лишней вложенности.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, покумекав над этой и аналогичной задачей, я решил проблемы с массивом.
1)Функцию `FindNearElement` я вынес перед `main`
2)В обьявлении функции я указал **исходный размер массива**, а не тот, что я пытался передать (а пытался я передать ограниченный кусок оного). То есть, привел к виду
`double FindNearElement(int numStr, int numCol, int a[N][M])`, где `N` и `M` - иходные размеры массива, заданные как глобальные переменные.
3)Вывод ближайшего к среднему значению элемента массиву я переместил из `main` в `FindNearElement`, ибо я понял что не могу вернуть из функции 3 аргумента (поправьте меня, если я не прав)
4)По совету @wololo добавил `fabs` при подсчете разницы
Конечный листинг функции привожу ниже. Благодарю всех за наводки и советы.

```
double FindNearElement(int numStr, int numCol, int a[N][M])
{
    float aver = 0.0, minDif, dif;
    int i, j, sum = 0, numPos = 0;
    int elStr, elCol;

    for (i = 0; i < numStr; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < numCol; j++)
            if (a[i][j] > 0)
            {
                sum += a[i][j];
                ++numPos;
            }      
    if (numPos > 0)
    {
        aver = (double)sum/(numPos);
        }
    else
        printf("\nMatrix have not positive elements!\n");

    elStr = elCol = 0;
    minDif = fabs(aver - a[0][0]);
    for (i = 0; i < numStr; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < numCol; j++)
            if (a[i]>0){
                dif = fabs(aver - a[i][j]);
                if (dif < minDif)
                {
                    minDif = dif;
                    elStr = i;
                    elCol =j;
                }
            }
        printf("\nElement nearest to average %.2lf of positive elements: %d\n", aver, a[elStr][elCol]);
    return aver;
}
```